# Uncaught typeerror: undefined is not a function for .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, undefined, typeerror

I'm trying to put together a basic, customizable horizontal scroller based on the code provided here:
http://jsfiddle.net/atAHh/261/ but when actually applied to the page, the javascript isn't taking.

Chrome developer is giving me 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' on the second line of the code below:

```
//Start the scrolling process
$(".panner").on("mouseenter", function () {
    var data = $(this).data('scrollModifier'),
        direction = parseInt(data, 10);
```

and also with the brackets at the very end:

```
}());
```

Full javascript, CSS, and html are in the jsfiddle, and these are the scripts my html references (pofoscroll.js being the problematic script):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/pofoscroll.js"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Checked the fiddle in MAC latest FF, everything works and no js error

Comment: Your fiddle works just fine. Are you waiting for the DOM to be ready in your actual page? `$(document).ready(function() { // your code... });`

Comment: try changing `(function () {` to `$(function() {` and the end to `})`. See, when it's loaded in fiddle, what's loading is `$(window).load(function(){
(function () {` which is comparable to `$(function() {`

Comment: Switched to $(function() { and updated the jquery version- all better.  Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: To me, this question was a savior. This shouldn't be downvoted!

Answer (score 4):

For me it looks like you're using jquery v.1.6 and .on() event was added in v.1.7